# Ignore blank/0 values in AVERAGEIF with two ranges

Tags: microsoft-excel, time, average

Trying to calculate average waiting time but, need to ignore blank or 0 value cells.

For example, here i'm calculating time difference between H column and G column and getting the average. However, the expected result should be 10 minutes. But it does not exclude blank or 0 value cells.

The formula i have used so far is `=AVERAGE((H5:18)-(G5:18)`
What can i do to make this all happen in one cell but also exclude 0 and blank values?

[image: Example image]

Comment: Try `=AVERAGEIF((H5:18)-(G5:18),"<>0")`.

Comment: I have atttempted that but, I get an error message asking if i am trying to make a formula.

Comment: It might be complicated as times so 00:00 is midnight.  You might want to add a helper column to calculate the wait and do the average on that. You can hide that column and still do the math on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like SUMIF and COUNTIF, AVERAGEIF will only accept a ***range*** as the first parameter. Subtracting range G5:G18 from range H5:H18 results in an ***array*** of values, which is not accepted.

As a workaround, you could calculate the average the old fashion way, by summing the values and dividing by the count of cells that are not empty:

```
=SUM(H5:H18-G5:G18)/COUNTA(H5:H18)
```

Alternatively, you could also use a helper column to perform the calculation, then use AVERAGEIF on the helper column only. For example, in cell F5, use the formula `=H5-G5`, and copy it down to cell F18. Then, the AVERAGEIF function would work, as follows:

```
=AVERAGEIF(F5:F18,"<>0")
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: You bet! Additionally, if you have Office 365, you could use `=LET(arr, H5:H18-G5:G18, AVERAGE(FILTER(arr, arr<>0,0)))`